# What is "context" in TypeScript & React for getServerSideProps (general question)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to coding and have a general question about this syntax I came across. I don't understand this line of code and couldn't find anything on the web to help me understand it:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
    const { getProduct } = await import('../../util/database');   
    const productId = context.query.productId; // is a string   
    ...  
}
```

(This is not the entire code, only the relevant part)

So what I don't get is:

- What is this context (I've read it makes props globally available?)? It looks like a type definition for TS-
- Is this context coming from React or TS?
- Does it function like props from React?

Comment: I found that too, but it's just hard to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I was just overwhelmed at the point where I asked the question. Coding is such a huge topic, kinda intimidating.

Answer (score 3):

> What is this context (I've read it makes props globally available?)? It looks like a type definition for TS-

That's React's [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). This is a Next.js thing instead which is [described here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) as an object with various information about the page/route the server side code handles. From that documentation:

> When exporting a function called `getServerSideProps` (Server-Side Rendering) from a page, Next.js will pre-render this page on each request using the data returned by `getServerSideProps`. This is useful if you want to fetch data that changes often, and have the page update to show the most current data.

Continuing with your questions...

> Is this context coming from React or TS?

Neither, it's coming from Next.js.

> Does it function like props from React?

Not really (at least, not the generic React props concept), but it can *return* something that includes props for the page component.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's still complicated for me, being new to it, but the precise answers helped.